# vb.net add value in combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox, integer

I'm currently adding values into a combobox using a For statement but this cannot be the best solution?

Combobox needs to be filled with values based on 1 variable integer.

```
Dim oOptions As Integer = 5
```

This should fill my combobox as:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Now i'm using but is there another way to do this?

```
For i = 1 to oOptions
```

Comment: So what is the problem here?  Why do you need "another way"?  What's wrong with this way?

Comment: you can declare an array
Dim Lst() as Integer = {1,2,3,4,5}
cmbOptions.DataSource = Lst

Comment: I'm not saying there is anything wrong, i'm just wondering if there is a better / more efficient way to do this? I'm not saying this is wrong.

Comment: How MORE efficient can you add a few digits to a combo box?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one line, code-efficient way, not execution efficient because Linq is syntax sugar

```
cboBox.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(Function(x) x).ToArray()
```

Now, replace `1` And `10` with variables and this will be very dynamic one-liner